# Combine every 100 html files into 1

Tags: linux, terminal

I have `1,000,000` html files, and want to combine every 100 html files into 1 html file. The final result would be `10,000` html files.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0):

you can do bash script for example

```
   #!/bin/bash
    for i in files(i=0, i<100, i ++);
      do  
                paste -d >> $i  
      done
```